# Audio mixer replacement for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, audio-recording

Similar to how Notepad can be replaced by many text editors. Is there something to replace Windows XP built-in simple audio mixer (sndvol32.exe), with something more versatile?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The mixer app in Windows does everything your sound card does, except for any proprietary features, which can be handled with the bundled software that came with your sound card.  If you're looking for EQ, separate channels per application, etc., then I recommend using loopback sound devices and a package such as Ableton Live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control both *playback* and *record* more efficiently than with Windows default volume control, [Audio Control](http://www.mbbsoftware.com/Products/Audio-Control/4/Default.aspx) is better. Also it is not bloated with unwanted features.

Answer (score 2):

Such alternatives usually goes with sound cards.

Answer (score 2):

I think Nirsoft's [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) is the best application for that purpose.

[image: Volumouse window]

It outputs a little scrollable window over the active window when <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>LMB</kbd> is held, by default, as shown below:

[image: Activated Volumouse]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Sound Control](http://www.reallyeffective.co.uk/sound-control/)